# ideas for creating a report

Tags: report, cognos-bi, cognos-11

Colleagues, I really need your advice on how to create a report with the following format in Cognos Analitics:
[image: report]

I only have the value "amount of money" and the dimensions "date" and "Person", and I need to display in the report the value for a specific date, and the change from the previous date.
for example, 01.02.2018 Person1 had 50 of the money, and 01.03.2018 Person1 had 61, so field № 3 is equal to 11 (61-50).
As you can see, there is no "change" column after the first field, because there is nothing to compare it with.
Do you have any ideas on how to generate such a report?

P.S. user selects the start date and end date of the report independently in the invitation

Comment: What version of Cognos? and do you have access to the metadata/framework manager OR can you ask a person that does?

Comment: hi, @VAIJason! 
I use Congos 11.1.
Аlso I have access to framework manager

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try creating multiple metrics

- Call the first Day 1 Amount
- Call the second Day 2 Amount
- Call the third Day 3 Amount

You could even define each metric relative to the other
Day 1 is based on the date selected
Day 2 is for the prior day
Day 3 is 2 days before... etc

Build the crosstab slightly different.  Instead of placing the metric in the middle
place them side by side

Then you can run calculations, %difference, growth etc on the fly